# Is it possible to virus scan a virtual disk file without mounting it?

Tags: anti-virus, virtual-disk

I've seen [dedicated virtual disk scanners](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH146500.html) before, but I am unsure if other antimalware products include this functionality.

Would it be safe to say that scanning a virtual disk file with the file scan functionality found in most if not all antimalware products would be sufficient, or would dedicated virtual disk scanning software or mounting the virtual disk be necessary?

Comment: Are you asking if scanning the virtual HDD file is enough to scan the content of that virtual HDD?

Comment: Yes. I'm also hoping that heuristic scannning will apply given an antimalware program's scan of the contents of the virtual disk file, but this is not a requirement.

Comment: I am not aware of any security software that would scan a virtual HDD without either being something like McAfee ePolicy Orchestrator or mounting the virtual HDD within the host OS, or an installation within the guest os.  By scanning the virtual HDD file you have confirmed the file itself isn’t malicious

Comment: So if I just scanned the virtual disk file without mounting it would pick up malware within the virtual disk?

Comment: My comment says the complete opposite.  I am not aware of a single AV program that does that.